# How do I configure Mercurial to use environment variables in mercurial.ini

Tags: variables, configuration, mercurial, environment

How can I modify the mercurial.ini file to include an environment variable such as **%userprofile%**.

*Specific situation*:

I am learning to use Mercurial.  I have modified the **[ui]** section of **Mercurial.ini** (in my home path) to include:

```
ignore = c:\users\user\.hgignore
```

Where *user* is my username literal.  The .hgignore file includes filename filters that are used to ignore files during commit. How can I alter it from being the a literal *user* to an environment variable $user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't interpolate environment variables in the hgrc, but I do believe that tilda expands to your home/profile directory correctly even on windows.

So:

```
ignore = ~/.hgignore
```

should work on windows and elsewhere (even the slashes get spun the wrong way automatically for you).

For other variables you'd need to get a little tricker and write a batch/cmd file that does the interpolation in advance and then hands the result off to mercurial for processing.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: +1 for `even the slashes get spun the **wrong** way automatically for you`

Answer (score 4):

The mercurial.ini parses the environment variables just fine.
From my mercurial.ini:

```
[ui]
ignore = %USERPROFILE%/.hgignore
```

Works like a charm.  Windows 7 Ultimate x64, Mercurial 1.5 (binary installation).  The hgignore file is honored both my the command line hg.exe, and tortoiseHG.